# Start Jboss using Ant from Jenkins

Tags: ant, jboss, jenkins

I was scripting an ant task in Jenkins through which I hoped to start jboss. I am getting it started, but soon I am getting such an error. Jboss version is 4.0.4

Problem starting service jboss
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGen space

I have set ANT_OPTS   and JAVA_OPTS  as follows

-Xms1536m -Xmx2048m -XX:PermSize=1536m -XX:MaxPermSize=2048m 
-Xmx2048M -XX:MaxPermSize=1024M -XX:MaxPermSize=1024M

This is what i did

```
<exec dir="${jbossHome}/bin" executable="cmd" spawn="true">
<arg line="/c run.bat"/> 
</exec>
```

I even tried to start jboss by executing run.bat from Jenkins, got same error.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

got that working with this.

```
<target name="start-jboss" depends="stop-update" >
   <echo message=" jboss\bin folder is  =  ${jbossHome}/bin"/>
    <exec dir="${jbossHome}/bin" executable="cmd" spawn="true">
    <arg line="/c run.bat"/> 
    </exec>
    <waitfor maxwait="50" maxwaitunit="second">
    <available file="errors.log"/>
    </waitfor>
</target>
```

Also gave this in run.bat of jboss.
set JAVA_OPTS=%JAVA_OPTS% -Xms512m -Xmx2048m -XX:MaxPermSize=512m